# Added item to ObservableCollection does not execute ICommand when clicked

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Below is the .axml for displaying an MvxListView bound to a list of objects named `EventDetailList` with each ItemClick bound to `DoEventDetailCommand`:

**EventDetailView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mvx.MvxListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource EventDetailList; ItemClick DoEventDetailCommand"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/event_detailitem" />
```

Upon clicking one of the items in this list an action is called within the ViewModel that adds another `EventDetailItem` to `ObservableCollection EventDetailList<EventDetailItem>` After this new item is added it immediately displays within the list. However, clicking this newly added item does not execute the `ICommand DoEventDetailCommand`. I have to navigate away from the screen and return in order for the newly added item to execute `DoEventDetailCommand` when it is clicked.

**EventDetailViewModel.cs**

```
    private ObservableCollection<EventDetailItem> _eventDetailList;
    public ObservableCollection<EventDetailItem> EventDetailList 
    {
        get
        {
            return _eventDetailList;
        }
        set
        {
            _eventDetailList = value;
            if(_eventDetailList == null ||
                _eventDetailList.Count == 0)
            {
               Close(this);
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => EventDetailList);
        }
    } 

...

public ICommand DoEventDetailCommand
{
  get
  {
    return new MvxCommand<EventDetailItem>(item =>
    {
      switch(item.ItemAction)
      {
        case EventDetailItem.Action.Information:
          break;
        case EventDetailItem.Action.DriverSig:
          EventDetailList.Add(new EventDetailItem() { 
            ItemAction = EventDetailItem.Action.Cancel, 
            IconImageType = EventDetailItem.IconType.Cancel, 
            Label = "Cancel" });
          break;
        case EventDetailItem.Action.Cancel:
          ShowViewModel<CancelTripViewModel>(new CancelTripViewModel.Nav() {Id=_curId});
          break;
        ....
```

Comment: does Stuart have some sort of bat-signal?

Comment: What type is `EventDetailList`? It should be an `ObservableCollection<T>` so data binding will occur when the collection changes.

Comment: EventDetailList is of type ObservableCollection<EventDetailItem> @Kiliman

Comment: Hmm, then I'm not sure why it's not working for you. I created a quick sample and binding works for me. Perhaps more code would help. How is `result` and `EventDetailList` related? Because ultimately you need to call `Add` on the observable.

Comment: Disregarding result variable, if I simply add an EventDetailItem to EventDetailList the binding doesn't work. @Kiliman

Comment: I'm afraid "the second item in the list is not binding to `DoEventDetailCommand`" doesn't really make sense - the items don't bind to `DoEventDetailCommand` - the list itself binds to that. Can you try editing the question to add more detail about what is/isn't working?

Comment: Sorry about that I edited the question again. Hopefully this makes more sense @Stuart

Comment: Does your debug trace show anything interesting when you add a new item?